# Anime identification - blue hovering surfboards and windmills

Tags: story-identification, anime

A few years ago on Netflix in the UK I saw the first episode or two of an anime where a young boy flies his hovering techno surfboard over a field, maybe with windmills in the background.

I'm afraid I can't remember any more details, except that maybe the title had blue in the name, or a synonym such as azure or cyan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like this might be [Eureka Seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_Seven).

This screenshot from the linked trailer shows the protagonist, Renton Thurston, riding his "reflection board" among the clouds:

[image]

A different screenshot, showing the windmill-like structures often present in the locations:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, pretty sure this is it. Hadn't realised it was actually still available! Thanks a lot for the help.